# Search with data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a UL with id "#menu-main" with children LI each having a unique data-arr attribute.
I made a search based on that data attribute.
But its not working.
Here is my code :

```
    function searchside(){
$('#menu-main').children('li').each(function () {

var str = document.getElementById("s").value;
var att = $(this).attr('data-arr').toString();

if(att.indexOf(str)!=-1)
{$(this).show();}
else
{$(this).hide();}

});
}
```

I am calling this function onkeypress of the input field with id "#s"
Can anyone help me out.

The HTML is :

```
<input type="search" onkeypress="searchside();" placeholder="Search" id="s" name="s"/>

<ul id="menu-main" class="menu">
        <li data-arr="royal preloader">
                <a  href='#!/royal_preloader' > 
                    <li class='cboth' >
                        <div class='fleft mediumline smallsquare inline blackbg aligntop smallgroup labelbg bgcenter' style='background-color:#171717;background-image:url(css/images/metroicons/white/32/mobile_home_white_32.png);'></div>
                        Homeee&nbsp;
                    </li>
                </a>
        </li>

        <li data-arr="noroyal preloader">
                <a href='#!/royal_preloader' >  
                    <li class='cboth'>
                        <div class='fleft mediumline smallsquare inline blackbg aligntop smallgroup labelbg bgcenter' style='background-color:#171717;background-image:url(css/images/metroicons/white/32/mobile_home_white_32.png);'></div>
                        Home&nbsp;
                    </li>
                </a>
        </li>

    </ul>
```

Comment: Can we please see your HTML code?  I have a feeling you have non-unique id's which are causing you problems.

Comment: Also, `attr()` returns a string, you don't need to call `.toString()` on it; and it might be worth switching to using `$(this).data('arr')` in place of using `attr()`.

Comment: you have nested li tag inside li tag that is not good, you should change it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$('#menu-main li').hide().filter('[data-arr="royal preloader"]').show();
```

To easily add in a filter based on search input just use this:

```
$('#s').on('keyup', function(){
    $('#menu-main > li').hide().filter("[data-arr*='"+this.value+"']").show();
});
```

Comment: @FREAKENGINEER - what do you want the end result to be? What would people enter into the search box to hide or show an `li`?

Comment: suppose user enters "abc" in the input field.. then the li with data-arr %abc% will be displayed and others will be hidden..

Comment: @FREAKENGINEER - no problem, I've also added a simple way to filter the `li`s based on the search input. It uses jQuery's [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$( '#menu-main' ).children( 'li' ).each( function ( i, el ) { 
    var el$ = $( el );
    if ( el$.data( 'arr' ) == 'royal preloader')
        el$.show();
    else
        el$.hide();
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function searchside() { ...
   $('#menu-main').find('[data-arr="royal preloader"]').show();    
   $('#menu-main').find('[data-arr!="royal preloader"]').hide();
}
```

based on your update

```
function searchside() { ...
   $('[data-arr="' + str +'"]').show();    
   $('[data-arr!="' + str +'"]').hide();
}
```

by the way you have nested li tag inside li tag, that is wrong, and you should change it